# How do I track and debug JavaScript memory leaks in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, mootools

I've been trying to track this one for literally a month now without any success. I have this piece of code on an car advertising website which basically allows thumbnails to rotate in search results given that a car has multiple pictures. You can see it in action at the following:

> [`http://www.abcavendre.com/4506691919/`](http://www.abcavendre.com/4506691919/)

It is built on the [mootools 1.2](http://www.mootools.net/) framework. The problem is that this script, under Firefox 3, consumes a rather large amount of memory overtime when a page is full of those rotating pictures, such as this inventory page:

> [`http://www.abcavendre.com/Vitrine/Israel_Huttman/`](http://www.abcavendre.com/Vitrine/Israel_Huttman/)

You can see the source of the script in question here:

> [`http://www.abcavendre.com/scripts/showcase_small.js`](http://www.abcavendre.com/scripts/showcase_small.js)

Any ideas as to what is causing the memory leak? The weird thing is this code behaves properly under IE7.

Comment: Did you solved it? If yes, what was the problem?

Comment: I did not manage to solve it. I am getting valuable information from the Leak Monitor Addon. I'm still working on it.

Comment: Disable Firebug if its enabled in any way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A way to track memory leaks in Firefox is with the [Leak Monitor Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/2490). It shows memory leaks of javascript (including extension-scripts).

Please remind that the plugin will sometimes show leaked objects that will get cleaned up later by the garbage collection. If that is the case the plugin will launch a new window showing you the new status.

Comment: You missed : after https, so SO makes a curious URL sending to TheEdge... :-)

Comment: Seeing as SO is an English-language site, you might want to provide an English-language link: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2490

Comment: Leak monitor no longer works with any of the modern versions of Firefox :-(

Comment: it's so sad that last addon's update have been made 5 years ago

Answer (score 0):

Try nulling elements variable array in the end of the initialize function

```
    ...

    if (ads.length > 0)
        {
        this.imagesFx = new Fx.Elements(elements,
            {
            wait: false,
            duration: 1000
            });
        this.moveNext.periodical(2500, this);
        }

    elements = null; //Add THIS!
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't explain the memory leak happening overtime (with no page refresh) as the initialize function is called only once per page.

Answer (score 0):

Update to MooTools 1.2.1, we've improved garbage collection and leak handling.